# Creating a function that sanitizes the custom metabox excerpt

Tags: php, metabox, excerpt

I'm still getting to grips with functions and experimenting with different php functions.

I've created a function what I want to use in sync with my custom metabox excerpt. It will basically sanitize the data and make sure its 150 characters long and the first word starts with a capital letter.

My code is very loose at the minute as I'm testing the functionality out, But am kind of lost as to how I should go about this, Sorry for any simple mistakes.

the $test_excerpt was just to test it, but at the moment it outputs nothing.

Code is below.

```
<?php

//Function that trims any access spaces either side of the excerpt incase it fails the validation run

$text_excerpt = "test";

function vs_trim_excerpt($text_excerpt) {
    if(isset($text_excerpt)) {
    trim($text_excerpt);
    ucfirst($text_excerpt);
    wordwrap($text_excerpt, 150);
    return $test_excerpt();
    } 
}

vs_trim_excerpt();
?>

add_action('init', 'vs_trim_excerpt');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this a WordPress question. It is really more just bad PHP but since that is a filter, in the spirit of fostering good will...

Your function is `return`ing a variable-name function that doesn't exist, and none of your operations are saved at all. You are processing the string but you aren't keeping the changes. You need to assign the results to a variable. And, you aren't feeding the function any information to start with.

```
$text_excerpt = "test";
function vs_trim_excerpt($text_excerpt) {
    $text_excerpt = trim($text_excerpt);
    $text_excerpt = ucfirst($text_excerpt);
    $text_excerpt = wordwrap($text_excerpt, 150);
    return $text_excerpt;
} 
echo vs_trim_excerpt($text_excerpt);
```

That should work better.

Comment: Aww thanks s_ha_dum, learn't 3 things already I can't code when im this tired and about saving the functions. does return save the value of the variable after going through all those functions?

Comment: Added another thing that I missed the first time though :)

Comment: No, it doesn't save anything. You need to `echo` the result or assign it to a variable.

Comment: Put a `echo` in front of the function call

Comment: I'll accept your awnser s_ha_dum, just need to manipulate this to work with my custom metabox field now :)

Comment: I know this is another question, but How would I append my metabox field data onto $text_excerpt?

Comment: You would concatenate it something like this: `$text_excerpt = $text_excerpt.' some content '.$avariable.' more content';` or `$text_excerpt .= ' some content '.$avariable.' more content';` I don't know if there is enough information to answer this second question in much detail.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some basic concepts of programming.

- [variable scoping](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)
- [return values](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)

Just because you define a variable in your first line it is not available in the scope of your function (it only exists in the global namespace). Also the functions you call actually return values. You need to assign the return values to a variable to use it. For example have a look at the PHP manual for [trim():](http://php.net/trim)

> Return Values:  The trimmed string.

You always should read the manual pages for the functions you use, so you'll see if they return anything and in what form it is returned.

```
function vs_trim_excerpt($text_excerpt) {
    $text_excerpt = trim($text_excerpt);
    $text_excerpt = ucfirst($text_excerpt);
    $text_excerpt = wordwrap($text_excerpt, 150);
    return $text_excerpt;
} 

$text_excerpt = "test";
$new_excerpt = vs_trim_excerpt($text_excerpt);
var_dump($new_excerpt);
```

Comment: This should do the trick: `$text_excerpt = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'name-of-your-metabox-field', true );` This will only work inside the loop. Manual page is here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

Comment: It outputs it but doesn't seem to make the beginning word start in capitals.

Comment: You will need to aditionally apply your function:
`$text_excerpt = vs_trim_excerpt($text_excerpt);`

Comment: do you mean use $text_excerpt = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'name-of-your-metabox-field', true ); first then add $text_excerpt = vs_trim_excerpt($text_excerpt);

Comment: Yes, and after that you can output it. `echo $text_excerpt;`